# Please help me translating this little php function to perl

Tags: php, perl, translate

I have this function that i need in perl:

```
<?php
function dv($r){$s=1;for($m=0;$r!=0;$r/=10)$s=($s+$r%10*(9-$m++%6))%11;
return chr($s?$s+47:75);}
?>
```

I've got this from [here](http://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~mortega/microcodigos/validarrut/php.php), where is already a perl function intended to do the same task ([here](http://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~mortega/microcodigos/validarrut/perl.html)) but it doesn't calculate correctly sometimes. PHP function does work perfectly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `#!/do/it/yourself !not -code -translation -service`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That PHP can be translated into perl rather directly:

```
sub dv{
   my $r=pop;
   my ($s, $m) = (1, 0);
   for(;$r!=0;$r/=10) {
      $s=($s+$r%10*(9-$m++%6))%11;
   }
   return chr($s?$s+47:75);
}
```

Extra newlines because... wow. That's ugly.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! It looked like elvish to me.